# Запятая в стихотворении (моём)

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая? Какая?

> А как же мне / В написанной ручонкой строчке / Вам рассказать / О фантазивном смехе Вашем, / Который(,) вызвать чтоб хоть попытаться(,) / Безуспешно пали жертвой / Мильоны рыцарей на северных конях?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Можно так:**

*А как же мне,*

***В написанной ручонкой строчке**,*

*Вам рассказать*

*О фантазийном смехе Вашем,*

*Который вызвать **чтоб хоть попытаться**,*

Безуспешно пали жертвой

*Мильоны рыцарей на северных конях?*

**Пояснение**

1. **Факультативное** обособление: *в написанной ручонкой строчке.*
2. ...*о смехе вашем, чтобы хоть попытаться вызвать **который**, безуспешно пали жертвой многие рыцари...*

Союзное слово ***КОТОРЫЙ*** может находиться не только в начале, но и **в середине** придаточной части. **[Источник](https://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/293-slognopodchinennoepredlogeniespridatochnymiopredeleniyami.html).**

В данном случае использована **инверсия** сочетания "который вызвать" (вместо "вызвать который"). Такая инверсия меняет расстановку логических **ударений** и подчеркивает **значимость** нужных слов соответствии с авторским замыслом.

Comment: Интересно, какой это стиль? Верлибр (свободный/вольный стих) или что-то еще? Верлибром называют изящную прозу, замаскированную под поэзию.  Это нечто среднее, не поэзия и не проза. И это не белый стих (без рифм), Ритмическое пространство верлибра организовано особенным образом. https://pishi-stihi.ru/verlibr.html   https://dzen.ru/a/YNS92jcS61VAJ2dY

Comment: Мне не нравится такое обособление.

Comment: Факультативное обособление не является обязательным.  Это авторский выбор.

Comment: Вероятно, вы правы.  В стихотворении такого стиля ритмику задает деление на строки, а это сочетание выделено в отдельную строку.

Comment: Но если есть сомнения в постановке запятой, то могу записать упрощенный вариант текста: о смехе вашем, чтобы вызвать который, безуспешно пали жертвой многие рыцари...  С.с. КОТОРЫЙ  в роли дополнения может стоять даже в КОНЦЕ придаточного предложения.